# Symmetrized tensors of Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Is there a simple formula (or maybe a table) to decompose the vector space $V^{\otimes{n}}$ of a (semisimple) Lie algebra with respect to the irreps of the symmetric group $S^n$? Example (I use chemists irrep notation, sorry :-): Take a member of the $E_7$ series. $V^{\otimes{4}}$ (with some ascii art) consists of ||,=,X and the quartic casimir Q. The first three symmetrize to $A_1+2E$, Q is antisymmetric ($A_2$). When I now try to build $V^{\otimes{6}}$, I can use no Q ($15=A_1+H_1'+L_1$), one ($15=H_2+M_2$) or two ($10=H_2+H_1'$). (One $H_2$ drops out due to the Jacobi relation.) And am promptly stuck on the remaining sextic casimir (is it symmetric or antisymmetric - I forgot...)
Cvitanovic's "Birdtracks" unfortunately says too little about the $E_7$ series to progress, also: how do (the shape of) Young tableaux relate to $S^n$ irreps?

Comment: No, unless your $V$ or your $n$ are somewhat special (or small). Your general question contains computation of plethysms in type A, which is far from simple...